# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, grails, jdbc, groovy, ggts

I realize this is what would be considered a duplicate topic, but I have followed the recommended steps in the other topics of this same nature with no success.

I am using GGTS 3.6.4 with

- Grails 2.3.0
- jdk1.7.0_80
- Groovy compiler level 2.3
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I have a grails-app which authenticates users logging in against an LDAP server with Apache Shiro and I have the following code (in the Shiro generated `AuthController.groovy`) to try and store some information from an external database in the session. (Note: With regards to usernames, passwords, and database names, I've changed all of them here for privacy reasons)

```
def signIn = {
    Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    String lowerCaseUserName=params.username.toLowerCase();
    def authToken = new UsernamePasswordToken(lowerCaseUserName, params.password)

    // Support for "remember me"
    if (params.rememberMe) {
        authToken.rememberMe = true
    }

    try{
        subject.login(authToken)

        if (subject.isAuthenticated()) 
        {
            session.username = lowerCaseUserName

            // Attempting to get employee id from MS SQL
            Sql Database = Sql.newInstance(
                'jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;DatabaseName=mydatabase',
                'user',
                'password',
                'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
            );
            Database.eachRow('select empid from table_name where username=${session.username}') { row ->
                session.empid = row.empid
            }
            Database.close();   

            def targetUri = params.targetUri ?: "/home"
            log.info "Redirecting to '${targetUri}'."
            redirect(uri: targetUri)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I get the following error

```
SQLException occurred when processing request: [POST] /app/auth/signIn - parameters:
username: user
_rememberMe: 
targetUri: 
password: ***
No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;DatabaseName=mydatabase. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;DatabaseName=mydatabase
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at app.AuthController$_closure3.doCall(AuthController.groovy:45)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried the following with no success:

- Added sqljdbc4.jar to /app/lib/
- Manually added /app/lib/ to classpath (via .classpath)
- Added sqljdbc4.jar to the classpath via the `Properties` > `Java Build Path` > `Add JARs`

I've tried these variations with sqljdbc4.jar, sqljdbc.jar, and sqlserverjdbc.jar and every combo thereof.

I'm basically stuck. None of the fixes I've read on here, or elsewhere, solve my error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit 1: Adding `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` above the `newInstance` call produces the following errors:

```
ClassNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [POST] /app/auth/signIn - parameters:
username: user
_rememberMe: 
targetUri: 
password: ***
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
at isec.AuthController$_closure3.doCall(AuthController.groovy:45)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is this a step forward, backward, or are we running in place?

Edit 2: What I ended up having to do was change my `DataSource.groovy` to this

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    //cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate"
            url = "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1433;databaseName=mydatabase;"
            driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            username = "myusername"
            password = "mypassword"
        }
    }
....
}
```

and changed my `AuthController.groovy` data access to

```
    try{
        subject.login(authToken)
        if (subject.isAuthenticated()) 
        {
            ShiroUser currentUser = new ShiroUser()

            def targetUri = params.targetUri ?: "/home"
            log.info "Redirecting to '${targetUri}'."
            redirect(uri: targetUri)
        }
    }
```

and I have successfully accessed my DB with a modified `ShiroUser.groovy` file

```
class ShiroUser {

    static hasMany = [ roles: ShiroRole, permissions: String ]

    User_Data userData;

    static constraints = {
    }

    def getUsername() {
        return userData.username
    }
}
```

where `User_Data.groovy` is a new domain class containing

```
class User_Data {

    static mapping = {
        table "mytablename"
    }
    ...
}
```

So now I'm onto messing with methods! Not sure why JDBC stuff didn't work out, but GORM is the path I'm taking now.

Comment: I don't know about Groovy, specifically, but you need to actually load the class in Java.  Try `Class.forName("package.name.for.DriverClassName");`.

Comment: Posting updated errors with your change

Comment: As per the error message the driver jar file is certainly not on the classpath.  As you said the driver jar file is in the app/lib folder I'd recommend to run `grails run-app` and skip the IDE.

Comment: Running from command line didn't change anything

Comment: Sometimes groovy (groovy console for me) can load driver (in sense load class) but not function as jdbc driver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494835/what-is-classpath-for-groovy-console-jdbc-driver-prblem In one way (of loading) is OK , in other not, `No suitable driver` in effect

Answer (score 0):

you definitely need to add sqljdbc4.jar to /app/lib/ which you have already done.

have you tried adding database connection to the BuildConfig.groovy

```
dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
        url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbName"
        username = "sa"
        password = ""
    }
```

Also make sure the SQL server is configured to accept connection on port 1433. It is disabled by default.

Comment: This is sort of what I had to do, but in the development environment

Comment: you can setup the datasource per environment
Ref: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#environments